# Play Framework 2.5 dependency injection in form object bean (Java)

Tags: java, playframework, dependency-injection

I was using the application static injector prior to play 2.5 in form objects to let those objects being responsible for their own validation and persistence mechanisms (with injected factories) in order to keep that logic out of controller objects.

However, the

```
    play.Play.application().injector().instanceOf(MyInterface.class);
```

is now deprecated and I wonder how I can get injected instances in my form beans, since there are no way to set values prior to the bindFromRequest() call.

Thanks for any tip...

Comment: Can you give an example for a form bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Play 2.5 it is :

```
Play.current().injector().instanceOf(MyInterface.class);
```

Here you can find [more tips for migration to Play 2.5](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/05/migration-play-24-to-play-25.html)